# How to average all items in a dictionary and average by key

Tags: c#, .net, linq, dictionary

I am new to using a dictionary in `C#`. I would like to know the **syntax** on how I could get the **Average** of all items and by Key. I'm not knowledgeable about `Linq` syntax also.

Below is the initialization of my dictionary.

```
Dictionary <string, double> scoreDictionary = new Dictionary <string, double>();
```

How can I get the **average** of the dictionary as a `WHOLE` and by specifying a certain`KEY`string? Is the `scoreDictionary.Average()` the method to be used?

Thank you very much!

Comment: What do you mean by "specifying a certain KEY string", the dictionary can't have duplicate keys, so a key will give you a value, what average are we talking about with a single value ?

Comment: I used `Dictionary <string, double>`. Let's say I added an entry: `scoreDictionary.Add('Key1', 80);` I want to **average** all entries that have 'Key1' as their `key`.

Comment: maybe you need `Dictionary <string, List<double>>`

Answer (score 3):

if you want to average the values for a certain key this would be the code

```
var averageForKey = scoreDictionary.Where(t => t.Key == "youKey").Average(t => t.Value);
```

Answer (score 2):

```
var averageScore = scoreDictionary.Values.Average();
var certainScore = scoreDictionary["Key"];
```

Comment: How can I **average** all values that have `keys = "Key"`?

Comment: @JPaulPunzalan seems you even not understand what a dictionary is

Comment: @JPaulPunzalan it's impossible to add several items with the same Key into Dictionary. You should use List<KeyValuePair<string,double>> instead.

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.